# Accessing fields from an ActiveRecord::Relation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I recently upgraded an app to Rails 4 and my data index page no longer has data in it. Referencing fields in the view no longer seems to output the correct information. Is there a new canonical way to access the data?

ex.

```
Controller:

def index
  @businesses = Business.all
end


View:
<% @businesses.each do |biz| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= biz.name %></td>
    <td><%= biz.tagline %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Result is a table with correct # of rows but blank cells.

Comment: If you run a similar block in your console, do you get the same blank output?

Comment: @jstim yes, the console is just as problematic.

I'm realizing that each is doing roughly what it should. The objects are there, the fields just aren't printing. My question title is no longer particularly relevant, though.

Comment: Edited title and question to reflect new understanding of problem.

Comment: I think we'll need to know more.

Comment: if you inspect the html page, can you see empty `tr` and `td` tags? If there aren't any, are you sure you have records in your db?

Comment: @jstim thanks for following up. Turns out that replacing attr_accessible with attr_accessor after the upgrade was not only redundant but caused all fields to be nil when I tried to access them.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for stopping in. You were right, in that the problem was entirely unrelated to the info I gave. It turned out to be that I should have completely removed the attr_accessible line from my models instead of changing it to attr_accessor. That change made all my fields nil when I went to use them in the view.

Comment: It's not so much that it "makes them nil" but that attr_accessor will replace the methods generated by ruby for accessing the model's persisted columns with methods to access regular instance variables.